# Why is MS Access 2010 SQL choking on this query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

The following query will not show up in design view and if you trying to make it show it locks up MS Access and you have to use the Task Manager to stop MS Access.  The query actually runs and produces the correct results.  If there is a better way I will certainly accept that.

```
SELECT
    log_metric_N.metric_title,
    log_metric_N.metric_N
FROM
    (
        SELECT
                tref_log_metrics_weights_and_factors.metric_title,
                [metric_base].[metric_count],
                [metric_base].[metric_sum],
                (([metric_base].[metric_count]*[tref_log_metrics_weights_and_factors].[metric_weight])/[metric_base].[metric_sum]) AS metric_N
            FROM
                tref_log_metrics_weights_and_factors,

                (
                    SELECT 
                        Count(tref_log_metrics_weights_and_factors.metric_weight) AS metric_count, 
                        Sum(tref_log_metrics_weights_and_factors.metric_weight) AS metric_sum
                    FROM 
                        tref_log_metrics_weights_and_factors
                    WHERE (((tref_log_metrics_weights_and_factors.metric_weight)<>0))
                ) as metric_base

    )  AS log_metric_N;
```

Comment: I don't know why it's locking up, but I can certainly understand why it's having difficulties displaying it in a design view. You have derived tables going two deep. I'm not sure how it would show you such a thing outside of the SQL editor.

Comment: @JNevill is there something wrong with derived tables? I don't like making a bazzillion standalone queries just to get to my desired end-state. Also if I move/copy a query and fail to get the sub-queries it breaks the prime query.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with derived tables, in fact I would recommend them over creating a bunch of queries and some crazy naming convention to keep the all seperate. Just be comfortable building your queries in the SQL view instead of the Design view since Access might not be able to give you a Design view version of your multi-level deep statement.

Comment: Does Design View still choke if you eliminate the implicit `CROSS JOIN` with that *metric_base* subquery and substitute `DCount` and `DSum` expressions to get the aggregate values you need from *tref_log_metrics_weights_and_factors*?

Answer (score 1):

@HansUp you were exactly right on. I forgot all about the Domain functions and they work perfectly without the complexity. Below is the resultant SQL statement.

```
SELECT
    tref_log_metrics_weights_and_factors.metric_title,
    DCount("[metric_weight]","tref_log_metrics_weights_and_factors","[metric_weight]<>0") AS metric_count,
    Dsum("[metric_weight]","tref_log_metrics_weights_and_factors") AS metric_sum,
    (([metric_count]*[tref_log_metrics_weights_and_factors].[metric_weight])/[metric_sum]) AS metric_N
FROM
    tref_log_metrics_weights_and_factors
```